# Windows Mobile SDK 6 Confusion

Tags: visual-studio, windows-mobile, compact-framework, windows-mobile-6.5

I am upgrading my Windows Mobile 5 project to a Windows Mobile 6 project.

The first step (at least so it seems to me) is to get the Windows Mobile 6 SDK installed.

When I went searching for this I found the following installs that both seemed to fit what I was looking for:

- Windows Mobile 6 Professional SDK Refresh.msi
- Windows Mobile 6.5 Professional Developer Tookit (USA).msi

So, the question is, do I need these both?  and if so, what order do I install them in? and is there any other installers/steps I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you're targeting.  There are loads of SDKs, but generally what they bring to the table are emulators and SDK-specific stuff (like additions to the Microsoft.WindowsMobile namespace).  Otherwise they really don't do a whole lot.  For example you can continue to use just the PPC 2003 SDK to write and deploy apps on WinMo 6.5, you'll just be missing availability of the stuff that was added to be 6.5-specific.

Persoanlly I'd recommend installing the 6.5 Pro (and maybe standard too) SDKs and foregoing the 6.0 SDK unless you need to do emulator testing for something like a 6.0 or 6.1 device.